# Reading chaquopy python.stdout and showing it in a TextView

Tags: android, chaquopy

I have a python script that logs messages to the python.stdout stream via print(). I can see the messages in the logcat console, but I want to be able to display those logs in my application. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adapting the open-source [console app template](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy-console).